# SMTP server for centOS, other than Postfix?

Tags: linux, centos, smtp

I need to install smtp server on centOS, but I don't want to use postfix.
please suggest some others smtp servers and how install using putty.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use postfix?

Answer (score 1):

sendmail!  It's your friend, assuming you like your friends terse and hostile.

I exaggerate.  I'm an old-time sysadmin and have grown up with sendmail, and I love it, though I concede it's not as friendly as some modern MTAs.  It's wicked powerful, though, and will generally not let you down if you go to the trouble of configuring it.  Also, many addons (greylisting, SPF checking, spamassassin integration) integrate well with it through the milter system, whereas some other MTAs either have the functionality built into the core, or you can't have it at all.

```
yum install sendmail sendmail-cf
```

will get you the binaries and the configuration tools.  http://www.sendmail.org/doc/sendmail-current/cf/README tells about the actual configuration, but the essence is: you write a short configuration configuration file (sic, `sendmail.mc`), which is run through the m4 language to produce the actual configuration file (`sendmail.cf`).  Unless you like pain, you **never** edit the .cf file directly, you always edit the .mc file and use m4 to regenerate the .cf.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of options for using SMTP on CentOS, up to CentOS 5 sendmail is the default SMTP but they're changing that for CentOS 6.

The easiest one in my experience is postfix, I would stick to that if I were you, if you don't want to do so you can change your smtp by doing the following

Use sendmail

```
yum install sendmail sendmail-cf
```

Use postfix

```
yum install postfix
```

If you want to use either qmail or exim4 they are not provided in the default CentOS repos, so you'll have to find alternate repos in order to install them

Here's some instructions in how to install qmail : http://qmailrocks.org/install_rh.htm

Here's also some instructions in how to install exim4 : http://www.exim-new-users.co.uk/content/view/97/1/

Comment: Why would you be so cruel as to mention Qmail?!

Comment: I personally find qmail also pure masochism but... he wanted all the options :D