# SMTP server for centOS, other than Postfix?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SMTP server for centOS, other than Postfix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/229550/smtp-server-for-centos-other-than-postfix)

Hello friends,

I want to install an smtp server on CentOS, but I don't want use Postfix.
Can you suggest some other smtp servers?

I'm very new to the Linux environment, so I will probably need step-by-step installation instructions.

Comment: If you tell us what you didn't like about Postfix, we may be able to provide better suggestions.

Comment: It is a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/229550/smtp-server-for-centos-other-than-postfix

Answer (score 0):

QmailToaster is rather good, and it works well with CentOS.

But this isn't the place to ask this sort of question!

Answer (score 0):

There's always Sendmail as an alternative. What is the problem with Postfix in your environment?